# SharePoint Online Document Checkin

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, check-in

I have a Document Library in SharePoint Online.
This contains Infopath form and an associated designer 2013 workflow.

When ever I check-in the form, the workflow gets triggered. 
But the form does not get checked-in at once. I need to check-in twice.

Not sure why this is happening.

Any suggestions?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Change the Designer workflow behavior to start when an Item is modified instead of created. Retry and see if the issue is resolve.